# How to modify wget output

Tags: wget

When I run **wge**t on a large file I get too much output.  It appears it outputs progress every 50K.

For example:

```
    0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  178K 22m8s
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  431K 15m38s
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  681K 12m20s
   150K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 1007K 10m14s
   200K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  993K 8m58s
   250K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  731K 8m22s
   300K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  570K 8m9s
   350K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  784K 7m46s
   400K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  770K 7m28s
   450K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  661K 7m19s
   500K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  753K 7m7s
   550K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  551K 7m7s
```

I don't want to use the **--quiet** option because I want to see output.  So what I'm looking for is a way to modify the output so that it outputs progress every 100MB instead of every 50K, or some other method.  Is there any option(s) I can use in wget in order to achieve a less verbose output?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/#index-progress-indicator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for link, answer was:

- MB: `wget --progress=dot:mega`
- GB: `wget --progress=dot:giga`

However, I chose progress bar, and had to add force parameter since output was not TTY

```
wget --progress=bar:force
```